# What is the name of this fractal?

Tags: fractals

[image]

I can't find the official name of this in my textbook. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: That looks like a graphical representation of the Cantor set.

Comment: The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), or more specifically, the Cantor middle thirds set or the Cantor ternary set.

Comment: looks like steps leading to the Cantor set

Comment: That is not a fractal.  That appear to be a fairly standard representation of the first several stages in a particular construction of a Cantor set (where the Cantor set is an archetypal fractal).  If you regard each row as one stage in the process, the Cantor set is the object that you get in the limit, i.e. the object in the "infinity-th" row.  That being said, to better answer your question, it would be helpful to know where you found that image.